# How to enter in DateTime in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

Some scope creep occured in the last couple of days and now I have to squeeze in date time.  The Oracle stored procedure has a Date field (same with the table).  Every time I try to enter in the date time value I get this refrain from the exception thrower:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
ORA-06512: at line 56
```

Here is what I try to enter:

```
SPECIALIST_APPT_DATETIMEIN := '09/Sep/1990 00:00:00'
```

Here is the param definition I try to squeeze it into:

```
PCP_APPOINTMENT_DATETIME`in `DATE`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to use the `TO_DATE` function to convert the string to a date.

```
SPECIALIST_APPT_DATETIMEIN := to_date('09/Sep/1990 00:00:00', 
                                      'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' );
```

assuming that you intend to enter times in the 24-hour format (i.e. 17:30:00 for 5:30pm).

Comment: I am entering in this date via ODP.Net... How can I do it on my client's side, before it hits the Oracle DB?